# JQuery- .wrap() the html of an element

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to turn an li into a div. I can use `.html()` to successfully get the inner HTML of the `li`, but I can't then `.wrap()` the returned contents in a `div`. I get the error "longHTMLstring has no method wrap".

Here's my mark-up:

```
<li class="ui-draggable">
    <h1>Some text</h1>
    <p>Some more text</p>
</li>
```

I am trying to turn that into:

```
<div>
    <h1>Some text</h1>
    <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery I am trying to use:

```
var s = $('.ui-draggable').html();
s.wrap("<div>");
```

I've tried chaining it in various configurations, but I breaking it down to clearest blocks now to try to work out the problem.

The full error I get is

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object <h1>Some text</h1> <p>Some more text</p> has no method wrap".
```

So I guess my problem is that `.html()` is giving me an object when I need a string? Do I need to do some nested `.clone()` chaining stuff to manage this?

Comment: `.html()` method will return **string** and you can **not** use jQuery methods (like `wrap`) on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('.ui-draggable').wrapInner('<div />').children().unwrap()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vtnAS/)

Comment: **+1** nice solution + nice jsFiddle Title (SO - ID) `;)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/): 
**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/UN4bX/)**

```
$('.ui-draggable').wrapInner('<div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fW9aB/1/)**

Chaning `li` element to `div` element, is invalid in HTML (as you always use `li` item in and `ol` or `ul`).
Buy the way, it will possible:

```
$('.ui-draggable').contents().unwrap().wrapAll('<div>');
```

---

References:

- [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) - jQuery API Documentation